# Why isn't this selecting correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have something very strange going on and I can't figure it out.

Whenever I have row like

```
<tr class="bold-and-caps">
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Partner planning</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="completeness avg" value="0.0" disabled="disabled"></td>
     <td><div class="readiness-circle"></div></td>
</tr>
```

selected by `$score_row` and I want to change the the `value` of the `input` and the CSS `background-color` of the `.readiness-circle`. I run

```
$score_row.find('input.completeness').val(average);
```

and that works.

Then I run

```
$score_row.find('.readiness-circle').css('background-color', newcolor);
```

and it doesn't work and in fact `$score_row.find('.readiness-circle')` doesn't select anything. I'm wondering does running `$score_row.find('input.completeness').val(average)` somehow screw up the context of the itself? I'm confused ...

**EDIT:** What the Hell is going on here? When do `.remove()` instead of `.css('background-color', newcolor);`, they are removed. So it doesn't have to do with the selector.

Comment: you haven't defined what `$score_row` is for us. Are you certain it refers to an actual element or is it null? If you open console do you see any errors?

Comment: @scrappedcola It's an actual row, I've verified.

Comment: Alright, I'll pose a more comprehensive question

Comment: Can you show how you define $score_row? Are you selecting as `$('.bold-and-caps')` or is something else defining it? Also can you go to jsfiddle.com and maybe make a working example of what you are doing? Sometimes a demo goes farther than just text (and can sometimes help you debug your issue).

Answer (score 0):

If the div has no content, the background color will not appear. Below I have two rows, one with a space in it and one without. Setting the color only affects the one that has content.

```js
var $score_row = $("tr");
average = 80;
newcolor = "yellow";

$score_row.find('input.completeness').val(average);
$score_row.find('.readiness-circle').css('background-color', newcolor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="bold-and-caps">
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Partner planning</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="completeness avg" value="0.0" disabled="disabled"></td>
     <td><div class="readiness-circle"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="bold-and-caps">
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Partner planning</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="completeness avg" value="0.0" disabled="disabled"></td>
     <td><div class="readiness-circle">&nbsp;</div></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the background color

Comment: Well the selector works, so unless your code is different than you need to make a demo with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $('tr.bold-and-caps').click(function () {
            $(this).find('.completeness').val('1111111');
            $(this).find('.readiness-circle').css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    });


</script>



<body>

   <table>
<tr class="bold-and-caps">
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Partner planning</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="completeness avg" value="0.0" disabled="disabled"></td>
     <td><div class="readiness-circle">hello</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="bold-and-caps">
    <td>Score</td>
    <td>Partner planning</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="completeness avg" value="0.0" disabled="disabled"></td>
     <td><div class="readiness-circle">hello</div></td>
</tr>  
</table>
</body>
</html>
```